# Mailmerge contact of same address & print directly from Civi

Tags: duplicate-contacts, mailing, pdf, printing

There was an extension from vedaconsulting for wordmailmerge extension. But seems its broken in 5.x. Just wondering if anyone can give me a alternative suggestion of how I can achieve the same result please?

I want to make PDF/DOCX or any printable format with contacts Name address etc. When generating docs, I would like to merge the name of the same address and option to eliminate "do not Mail" contacts.

Any ideas please? Thanks

Comment: You can do this directly in civicrm by creating a Message Template and then using Action = Print PDF from the Adv Search

Comment: Thanks. But I do not think it gives option to merge contacts of same address or filter "do not mail"

Comment: You can filter 'do not mail' in the Adv Search. For the 'merge contacts of same address', what do you want the actually outcome to be, eg if you have 7 people at same address does it join together all 7 names?

Comment: did you actually try the extension or just not see 5.x listed? if you tried it did you post an issue on veda's issue queue about their extension working for 5.x (5.x wasn't a substantive update from 4.x!)

Comment: Yes, if 7 people at same address it needs join together all 7 names. I have tried their extension and posted issue but no response so far.